# Uncaught type error: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, undefined

I have a problem when updating datapoint in canvas chart. I get this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘getTime’ of undefined

The output I receive in `response.msg` is

```
[{label: 'Purok I', y:1},{label: 'Purok II', y:1},{label: 'Purok III', y:2}]
```

When this is replaced with `response` renders the chart successfully. However passing response to `datapoints` gives the error. This is my Javascript. Any help?

```js
$('#barangay-list').click(function() {
  var barangay_id = $(this).val()
  console.info(barangay_id)
  $.ajax({
    url: '../classes/main.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      'population-chart': 1,
      'barangay_id': barangay_id
    },
    async: true,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response, data) {
      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        theme: "light2",
        zoomEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
        axisX: {
          title: "Street Name",
          gridThickness: .9,
          lineThickness: .9,
          titleFontSize: 14,
          labelFontSize: 12,
        },
        axisY: {
          includeZero: true,
          title: "Number of Population",
          gridThickness: .9,
          lineThickness: .9,
          titleFontSize: 14,
          labelFontSize: 12
        },
        toolTip: {
          shared: "true"
        },
        legend: {
          cursor: "pointer",
          itemclick: toggleDataSeries,
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          horizontalAlign: "center"
        },
        data: [{
          type: "spline",
          showInLegend: true,
          name: "Populaltion Number",
          dataPoints: response.msg
        }]
      });
      chart.render();

      function toggleDataSeries(e) {
        if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
          e.dataSeries.visible = false;
        } else {
          e.dataSeries.visible = true;
        }
        chart.render();
      }
    },
    // Error Handler
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
      console.info(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `getTime()` isn't called anywhere in this logic. If you double click the error in the console it will show you the exact line of your code which is causing the problem

Comment: There is no getTime() in your posted code, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: The problem is in dataPoints: response.msg

Comment: I solved it and my program working by the help with you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by the help with this concern people [Converting array with Different data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954845/converting-array-with-different-data-type/54954900?noredirect=1#comment96672333_54954900)

remove this code:

```
async: true,
dataType: 'JSON',
```

add JSON.parse() and map function

```
if(filename == "chart"){ 
    $('#barangay-list').click(function(){
      var barangay_id = $(this).val()
      console.info(barangay_id)
      $.ajax({
        url: '../classes/main.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
          'population-chart':1,
          'barangay_id': barangay_id
        },
        // async: true,
        // dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response,data){
          let datapoints = (JSON.parse(response))

          let result = datapoints.map(function(x) { 
              x.y = Number(x.y);  
              return x;
          });
          var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            theme:"light2",
            zoomEnabled: true,
            animationEnabled: true,
            animationEnabled: true,
            axisX: {
              title: "Street Name",
              gridThickness: .9,
              lineThickness: .9,
              titleFontSize: 14,
              labelFontSize: 12,

            },
            axisY :{
              includeZero: true,
              title: "Number of Population",
              gridThickness: .9,
              lineThickness: .9,
              titleFontSize: 14,
              labelFontSize: 12
            },
            toolTip: {
              shared: "true"
            },
            legend:{
              cursor:"pointer",
              itemclick : toggleDataSeries,
              verticalAlign: "bottom",
              horizontalAlign: "center"
            },
            data: [{
              type: "spline", 
              showInLegend: true,
              name: "Populaltion Number",
              dataPoints: 
                result
            }]
          }); 
          chart.render();

          function toggleDataSeries(e) {
            if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible ){
              e.dataSeries.visible = false;
            } else {
              e.dataSeries.visible = true;
            }
            chart.render();
          }

        },
        // Error Handler
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
          console.info(xhr.responseText);
        }
      }); 

    });


    $.ajax({
      url: '../classes/main.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data:{
        'admin_dashboard':1
      },
      async: true,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(response,data){

        $('#user_num').text(response.num_user)
        $('#barangay_num').text(response.num_barangay)
        $('#barangay_street_num').text(response.num_street)
        $('#position_num').text(response.num_position)
      },
      // Error Handler
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        console.info(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }); 

  }
```