# Converting array with Different data type

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

How to convert this in Javascript from:

```
[
   {
      "label": "Purok I",
      "y": "1"
   },
   {
      "label": "Purok II",
      "y": "1"
   },
   {
      "label": "Purok III",
      "y": "2"
   }
]
```

to:

```
[
   {
      label: "Purok I",
      y: 1
   },
   {
      label: "Purok II",
      y: 1
   },
   {
      label: "Purok III",
      y: 2
   }
]
```

Any help?

Comment: What's the difference? The stringified property names don't do anything.

Comment: I want to output values with different datatypes but it returns all string

Comment: Oh, I see - thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No problem @JackBashford

Comment: @john what is your intent for converting {"y":"2"} ==> {y:2}?

Comment: Yes @DenisSDujota, exactly

Comment: right, but what is the main purpose of trying to accomplish this?

Comment: I try to include that in canvasJS, because the graph will not work if all are return to string except for the value of label key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method will update all numeric types in your objects automatically.

```js
let arr = [{
    "label": "Purok I",
    "y": "1"
  },
  {
    "label": "Purok II",
    "y": "1"
  },
  {
    "label": "Purok III",
    "y": "2",
    "example": "432.23"
  }
];

// Map over your array of objects
arr = arr.map(obj => {
  // Map over all the keys in your object
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    // Check if the key is numeric
    if (!isNaN(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = +obj[key];
    }
  })
  return obj;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: What is the difference? All are string

Comment: You want it casted?

Answer (score 3):

Make all stringified numbers into non-stringified numbers using `map` and destructuring like so:

```js
const data = [
   {
      "label": "Purok I",
      "y": "1"
   },
   {
      "label": "Purok II",
      "y": "1"
   },
   {
      "label": "Purok III",
      "y": "2"
   }
];

const numbered = data.map(({ label, y }) => { return {label, y: parseInt(y)}});

console.log(numbered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

## EDIT

Turns out making string-less property names is impossible:

```js
var obj = {
  foo: "bar",
  one: 1
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: solid answer, doesnt address the fact that he wants to {y: 1} not {"y":1}.

Comment: great answer but that's not i wanted

Comment: All key and value are string . I want to have different data type, can u help me?

Comment: Sorry, fixed now @JohnCrisMañabo.

Comment: @JohnCrisMañabo It is impossible to do - see the above example.

Comment: Thanks for the help . My program is working . @JackBashford

Comment: No problem @JohnCrisMañabo always glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let  p = [
   {
      "label": "Purok I",
      "y": "1"
   },
   {
      "label": "Purok II",
      "y": "1"
   },
   {
      "label": "Purok III",
      "y": "2"
   }
]

let result = p.map(function(x) { 
    x.y = Number(x.y);  
    return x;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You solved my problem . Thank you very much . So much appreciation